# Download from browser files stores on server through Rest web services

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, rest

I have a project based on Spring (Spring security, spring controller e MVC ) so in my HTML page I have to allow file download.
When user click on this :

```
<a href="#" target="'+row.idCar+'" id="logName" name="logDownload"> <i class="fa fa-file-text-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>'
```

I handle event and use this code based on [jquery plugin](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/)

```
var input = $(this),
        idCar= $(this).attr('target');
        $.fileDownload("../download/" + idCar , {
            successCallback: function (url) {
            },
            failCallback: function (HttpServletResponse, url) {
                notifyMessage("Error downloading file", 'error');
            }
        });
        return false; //this is critical to stop the click event which will trigger a normal file download!
```

In my controller:

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(value="/download/{idCar}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void download(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable("idCar") int idCar) {
    try{
        File file = fleetAndCarService.getLogFile(idCar);
        try(InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath())) {
            response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "fileDownload=true; path=/");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                        "attachment; filename=\"" + "AcquisitionLog.txt" + "\"");
            org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(is,
                        response.getOutputStream());
            response.flushBuffer();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            ErrorResponse errorResponse= ErrorResponseBuilder.buildErrorResponse(e1);
            LOG.error("Threw exception in FleetAndCarControllerImpl::download :" + errorResponse.getStacktrace());
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        ErrorResponse errorResponse= ErrorResponseBuilder.buildErrorResponse(e);
        LOG.error("Threw exception in FleetAndCarControllerImpl::download :" + errorResponse.getStacktrace());
    }
}
```

But it has problem with Spring Security like this post [x-frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36603174/x-frame-deny-in-spring-security) and on internet explorer doesn't work. 
So, there is a way to download file stored on my server without use of plugin?
Thanks

**RESOLVED**:  Hansraj helped me and this is the working code:

```
try{
            File file = fleetAndCarService.getLogFile(idCar);
            try(InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath())){
                response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
                response.setHeader("Cache-Control","must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
                response.setContentType("text/plain");
                response.setHeader("Content-Description"," File Transfer");
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename="+"AcquisitionLog.txt");
                response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding"," binary");
                long size = Utils.stream(is, response.getOutputStream());
                response.addHeader("Content-Length", Long.toString(size));
                response.flushBuffer();
            }catch (Exception e1){
                ErrorResponse errorResponse= ErrorResponseBuilder.buildErrorResponse(e1);
                LOG.error("Threw exception in FleetAndCarControllerImpl::download :" + errorResponse.getStacktrace());
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            ErrorResponse errorResponse= ErrorResponseBuilder.buildErrorResponse(e);
            LOG.error("Threw exception in FleetAndCarControllerImpl::download :" + errorResponse.getStacktrace());
        }
```

in the HTML I used href with the url of web service.
Utils is the class suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10142601/4004025)

Comment: " doesn't work" How, exactly? What error do you get?

Comment: on chorme works with the error, on edge download doesn't start giving me
SCRIPT5009: 'goToLocalizedErrorPage' is undefined, forbidframingedge.htm (13,15), on explorer doesn't start and no error appears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample code that worked for me. You can try this sample

```
package com.mti.controller.booking;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/offlineBooking")
public class OfflineBookingController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/getInvoice")
public void getInvoice(ModelMap modelMap, @RequestParam(value = "bookingId", required = true) Integer bookingId,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    Document document = new Document();
    InputStream is = null;
    PdfWriter writer = null;
    try{
    String everything = bookingService.getBookingInvoiceData(bookingId);
    is = new ByteArrayInputStream(everything.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control","must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");

    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setHeader("Content-Description"," File Transfer");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename="+"BookingInvoice"+ bookingId+".pdf");
    response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding"," binary");
    writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());
    document.open();
    XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, is);
    writer.flush();
    response.flushBuffer();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error in generating invoice " , e);
    }finally{
        if(writer!=null){
            writer.close();
        }
        document.close();
        is.close();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: what about javascript side?

Comment: you have to provide the complete url in a href directly (do not use javascript)